# How to use tiny slider 2 with Magnific Popup plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

I want to use this plugin for sliding images: https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider with the Magnific popup plugin. Problem is that Tiny slider can't work when there is an image inside  tag (which I need for Magnific popUp). It works well when I have some container div and only images inside it, but not when I put image inside  It works, but not show me the image:
[Slider with one image set inside  tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOPd6.png)
Here is my code:

```
<div class="wed-slider">
                   <a class="popup-link" href="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-weddingBig-1.JPG">
                        <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-1.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 1">
                    </a>
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-2.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 2">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-3.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 3">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-4.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 4">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-5.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 5">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-6.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 6">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-7.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 7">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-8.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 8">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-9.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 9">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-10.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 10">
                    <img src="img/weddings-other/mtphotobl-wedding-11.JPG" alt="MT photography vjencanje 11">
       </div>

//Weddings slider
var slider = tns({
    container: '.wed-slider',
    controls: false,
    arrowKeys: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    autoplayButtonOutput: false,
    lazyload: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    responsive: {
      640: {
        edgePadding: 20,
        items: 2
      },
      700: {

      },
      900: {
        items: 6,
        gutter: 10,
      }
    }
  });

//Weddings popup
$('.wed-slider').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
  type: 'image'
  // other options
});
```

Someone know solution for this?